# Datatable always return second value

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, datatable

I found some strange behavior for which I haven't found a solution yet. when I debug SQL code, it returns correct value, but somehow in C# code, datatable returns wrong result.

Due to fact that this is billing application and it has sensitive information, I cannot publish whole code, only method which contains problematic code and SQL stored procedure which returns result.

SQL:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[conf_SetRationCurrency] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
DECLARE @Date AS VARCHAR(10),
      @Today AS VARCHAR(10)

SELECT @Date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[date], 112) FROM RatioCurrency
SELECT @Today = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),112)

BEGIN TRAN
BEGIN TRY
   IF @Date <> @Today
   BEGIN
      -- INSERT
      INSERT INTO dbo.RatioCurrency 
      SELECT rateType, CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112) AS SMALLDATETIME) AS [date],fromCurrency,toCurrency,value 
      FROM dbo.RatioCurrency where [date] = 
      (
      SELECT TOP 1 CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, [date], 112) AS SMALLDATETIME) AS [date] 
      FROM dbo.RatioCurrency 
      ORDER BY ID DESC
      )       
      SELECT 'Yes' AS 'INSERTED' -- return flag for setting output text in code
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
      SELECT 'No' AS 'NOT' -- return flag for setting output text in code 
   END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
      ROLLBACK TRAN
      EXEC dbo.intf_ShowError
      RETURN
END CATCH
COMMIT
END
```

C#:

```
     DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Da li želite kopirati valutu zadnjeg unosa za današnji dan...?","Upit",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            DataTable dt = Program.ExecProc("conf_SetRationCurrency");

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0 && dt.Columns[0].ColumnName == "ErrorNumber")
            {
                Program.ShowDataInfoError(dt.Rows[0]); //print error message
            }
            else if (dt.Rows.Count > 0 && dt.Columns[0].ColumnName == "NOT") //part which should only give info that value is already in the database, no need to insert new one. 
            {
                SplashForm sf = new SplashForm();
                sf.informationText.Text = "Valuta već postoji.";
                sf.Show();
                GetCurrency();
                this.Refresh();
            }
            else // this part actually gives info that new values are inserted
            {
                SplashForm sf = new SplashForm();
                sf.informationText.Text = "Valuta je upisana.";
                sf.Show();
                GetCurrency();
                this.Refresh();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
```

Even though SQL is returning correct colum name value, datatable is returning column name - "NOT" (a second one) and I mean always... This cannot be true since I have if/else statement and program should avoid second statemement. How the hell is datatable object holding wrong column name? is this a bug or since I'm using alias for columns so it uses last one...? Does anyone have an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Once had the same problem, though not in C#:

The cause was that by accessing the query-result by php the pointer was allready moved, so the first result was always skipped.

Sounds like the same kind of Problem, might be the rowcount.

(sorry can't just comment)

Comment: well, I couldn't say that it has to do with rowcount because in visual studio when I set DataTable object into "Add to Watch" and see his properties, I can see that RowCount is 1, so it has value...

Answer (score 1):

ADO.NET is caching the DataTable structure (column names & types) returned from the stored procedure. It is not a good idea to change the table structure based on business logic - rather vary the data than the structure.
I suggest you change the sp so that it always returns the same column name, e.g. "Status" but the *value* changes depending on your business logic.

```
--SQL logic
if (errorCondition)
  SELECT 'ERROR' as Status, 'Error message' as Message
if @Date <> @Today
   SELECT 'Yes' AS Status, '' AS Message
else
   SELECT 'No' AS Status, '' as Message
```

Then your C# logic becomes simpler in that:

- there is always one row of data returned with a fixed number of columns and with fixed names
- you can use the *values* in the single row returned for your business logic

Comment: I did play with code, but had same result eg. 
    `SELECT @val = 'Yes'
   ...
    ELSE
    BEGIN
    SELECT @val = 'No'
    END
...
SELECT @val AS TEMP
`
and C#:
`
dt.Columns[0].ColumnName == "TEMP"
`
where dt.Rows[0][0].ToString().Equals("Yes"), still no solution... it looks like user: evlive is right. it has to do with pointers that are skipping first value

Comment: sorry I misspelled nickname - it is: @evilive

Comment: If you can see that the DataTable contains just one row, and you can retrieve a value from that row, then there are no pointers that are being skipped. You're accessing the row[0] with an absolute index, so no pointers involved. OK I think the problem is in your first statement `SELECT @Date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[date], 112) FROM RatioCurrency` that will always retrieve the date from the first row of your table. It will only work if `RatioCurrency` only contains a single row but in the SP you are adding rows so there's your problem.

Comment: well I did need only one row to compare with current date. the thing is if insert is not done automatically you can do it manually, so first it checks last day which I corrected to:

`SELECT TOP 1 @Date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[date], 112) FROM RatioCurrency ORDER BY id DESC` 

and compare it with current date. if it is different than insert should occur, but if not, skip and send only a "flag" for c# code...